# Pick the first record with a value

Tags: stata

```
nparasit    numserial   ndate_added
    .       42231       05-Jun-00
    7992    42231       03-Jun-00
    .       422420       4-Jun-00
    144000  42242       05-Jun-00
    712800  42242       04-Jun-00
    NEG     42242       08-Jun-00
    371200  42242       06-Jun-00
    10138   42242       07-Jun-00
    .       110224      21-Dec-11
    0       110224      12-Dec-11
```

I am using `Stata 12` on Windows 7. I have a data set with duplicated
numserials. I want to pick the first `nparasit` with a value according to
date added (`ndate_added`). I have tried using `bysort` but without
success . How can I go about it

Comment: This is cross-posting without explaining that. See http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2014-02/msg00176.html and following replies. It is, I suggest, poor practice not to tell people about suggestions received elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
// prepare some example data
clear
input ///
nparasit    numserial   str9 ndate_added
    .       42231       02-Jun-00
    7992    42231       03-Jun-00
    .       422420      04-Jun-00
    144000  42242       05-Jun-00
    712800  42242       04-Jun-00
    .       42242       08-Jun-00
    371200  42242       06-Jun-00
    10138   42242       07-Jun-00
    .       110224      21-Dec-11
    0       110224      12-Dec-11
end

gen date = date(ndate_added, "DM20Y")
format date %td

// mark first non-missing value on nparasit
gen byte miss = missing(nparasit)
bysort miss numserial (date) : ///
   gen byte mark = ( _n == 1) & ( miss == 0 )

// admire the result
sort numserial date
list, sepby(numserial)
```